# Restyling the scrollbar with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar

I'm currently thinking about making a custom jQuery scrollbar for only one of my pages so I can scroll through a set of pictures with a great scrollbar.

I tried looking a bit around, but I couldn't really find any tutorials for such a thing.  I do not want to use CSS3 since it is not supported by all browsers.

I haven't really used jQuery before, so a well-explained tutorial would be nice.

Comment: This is not a tutorial site. You try to write code, if it doesn't work you post your attempt, and then we help you fix it.

Comment: @Barmar Oh I am im sorry then, I was hoping if someone could direct me in some direction, so I have somewhere to start.